# Tomcat virtual host and context config

Tags: tomcat, virtualhost, context.xml

I'm having an issue accomplishing something. I currently own a domain and I have the DNS set up to hit Tomcat on 8080 on my local machine when requested in the browser. All good so far. So when it hits Tomcat I get the standard "Cat" page where I can access manager, host-manager, etc...

My goal is to set up a virtual host to have a request to my domain routed to a specific webapp located in the Tomcat_Home\webapp folder. So I configure my server.xml as such:

```
<Host name="dwnewton.com" appBase="webapps"
    unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

</Host>
```

The dwnewton.war has been deployed to webapps and has unpacked itself as expected. But no matter what I do I cannot get Tomcat to route my request to a specific webapp within the Tomcat_Home\webapp directory.

- I've tried putting context.xml in the Meta_Inf of the specific application
- I've tried configuring the context.xml in the conf directory
- I've tried putting the [appname].xml in the conf\localhost directory

I'm getting pretty frustrated. Perhaps I'm specifying the appBase or path or docBase incorrectly. Or maybe I'm putting them in the wrong location.

Answer (score 1):

If you rename dwnewton.war to ROOT.war, it should be available at the root of your domain.

Comment: You are correct that my application will be available it I put it all in the ROOT directory. There are a few workarounds like this that will solve my problem.

There are drawbacks. Lets say I navigate to http://localhost:8080 to manage my Tomcat instance. Not anymore. This is like making my webapp the default on this server. I could always navigate to the manager app but I would prefer not to. Also that limits me to one virtual host. Thats a no go. 

I would like to deploy my webapps inside the TOMCAT_HOME\webapps folder by their descriptive names.